# How to convert from MySQL date string YYYY-MM-DD into Visual FoxPro/DBF Date format

Tags: mysql, visual-foxpro

I'm new on Visual FoxPro and I have a problem trying to convert a string date MySQL formatted string with Visual FoxPro.

I have selected MySQL table rows from Visual Fox Pro app and store that result set in a FoxPro cursor but now I need to convert the values of that column (for each row) date which is not a MySQL date column but a char column with the MySQL date format (YYYY-MM-DD) so I have tried with something like this:

```
SCAN 
        REPLACE date_column WITH CTOD('date_column')  
        
ENDSCAN
```

but it does not work.

can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

If the column is a date column in MySQL, bring it across as a date. If not, your best bet with a known format is to parse it and use the DATE() function to build a date variable:

```
LOCAL nYear, nMonth, nDay, dDate
nYEAR = LEFT(m.cYourDate, 4)
nMonth = SUBSTR(m.cYourDate, 6, 2)
nDay = SUBSTR(m.cYourDate, 9, 2)
dDate = DATE(m.nYear, m.nMonth, m.nDay)
```

There are a bunch of other ways to do this, but as long as you know the format is always the same, this should work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that when you are doing a SQL Query into an "external", Non-Native Database you have to use that Database's SQL syntax (in this case use MySQL SQL syntax and not VFP's SQL syntax) on your initial query of data from the "external", Non-Native Data Table.

For example:

```
* --- Within your VFP code, establish your Connection into the MySQL Database ---
* --- Something like the following... ---
iHandle = SQLSTRINGCONNECT("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=xxxxx;Port=3306;Database=arc;User=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Option=3;",.t.)
* --- Now execute your MySQL SQL syntax query ---
* --- And get the results back into your VFP Cursor named: crsData ---
SQLEXEC("SELECT 12345 AS id FROM arc_data", "crsData")
```

So first, determine what field type you are working with in your MySQL Data Table - Character, Date, DateTime, whatever.

Then, if needed, use the appropriate MySQL SQL syntax to convert it to a Character representation of the Date in your SQL Query results.

Now with that Character value of the Date in your Query results, you can use Tamar's routine above (nested in a SCAN/ENDSCAN) to convert each record's date - although this new value type will need to go into a new VFP field since the existing field is a Character type and not a Date type.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Best way of doing this is to make the conversion while selecting from  MySQL. Your SQL would look like:

```
select field1, field2, cast(myCharDate as date) as myDate
from mySQLTable
```

If you want to convert from that YYYY-MM-DD format after getting into a cursor, you need to know a few points. The cursor may or may not be a read/write cursor. If it is not then you don't have a chance to make changes directly on that cursor. If it is read/write then you can't replace a character type field's value with a date value but you can add another column of date type and replace there (or might simply change the existing column's type to date which would also do the conversion provided you SET DATE YMD).

However, the easiest way would be selecting into another cursor like:

```
select field1, field2, cast('^'+myCharDate as date) as MyDate ;
from crsMyCursor ;
into cursor crsConverted ;
nofilter
```

Why are you keeping a Date value in a char typed field is another question. Normally you would keep dates in date or timestamp column and wouldn't have a need for conversion at all. Keeping dates in char column has its own problems like sorting, doing date math inability etc.